# Executor.execute() JMM guarantee

Tags: java, concurrency, java-memory-model

Consider the following code snipet:

```
public class A {

    private final Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    private final Queue<Object> messageQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<M>();

    public void sendMessage(Object message) {
        messageQueue.offer(message);
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Object message = messageQueue.poll();

                // Can message == null? 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is it guaranteed that messageQueue contains the message by the time when the Runnable instance will try to retrieve it? Or to phraise it a little bit more general: can two function calls be reordered by JIT/JVM according to JMM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if there are not other producers/consumers.

`Executor.execute()` establish a *happens-before* relationship. Therefore everything in `offer()` *happens-before* `poll()`. `poll()` sees the effect of `offer()`. Although not formally specified, by any common sense, `poll()` should then return the object just added to the queue.

Comment: Could you please provide a reference to a document where this happens-before relationship for Executor.execute() is guaranteed, for I see nothing like that in the respective Javadoc http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

Comment: The happens-before relationship is indeed documented but starting from Java 6:

"Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to submitting a Runnable object to an Executor happen-before its execution begins, perhaps in another thread." http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

So, thank you very much Mr. Irreputable :)