# Variables inside Executor's Runnable

Tags: android, executor

Suppose I have a Runnable that does a simple file writing operation, and this Runnable is called with an executor.

With executor being a single thread Executor class..

```
public void doThis() {
    executor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            file.write(_data);
        }
    });
}
```

does the immediate contents of _data get saved the moment execute() is called? Which means that once the runnable has been submitted to the queue, I can go ahead and make changes to _data, and the changes will not be written to the file?

```
_data = something
doThis();
_data = something else
```

is there a chance that I will end up doing file.write(something else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no to your first and second questions, and yes to your third question ... if the single thread that the executor is running on is a separate thread from the calling thread, then this is not a thread-safe operation. unless .execute() executes on the same exact thread as the caller, you need to avoid making changes to _data until .write is done.

A common way of working around this is to simply make a copy of _data before passing it off to the executor.

Comment: the problem with this is that I will have many changes to _data and want to call execute() immediately on the new _data. In this case I guess the only choice I have is to implement some sort of data structure _data, so that execute() will always work with _data[].oldest?

Comment: there is a similar question posted (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147015/executor-execute-jmm-guarantee), in which they talked about memory consistency and how an "Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to submitting a Runnable object to an Executor happen-before its execution begins, perhaps in another thread."

I was hoping that by the same logic, the _data = something does NOT happen before doThis(). However I am not very sure about what "actions in a Thread happening before" mean. Could it still be possible?